# How to get refresh token with personal access token in laravel passport

Tags: laravel-8, refresh-token, personal-access-token

Thanks for help
I am working on a project with laravel in backend and react js on the front end

I cannot understand how to issue refresh token along with personal access token

Createtoken('token_name')->accesstoken();
Only issues an access token

Answer (score 4):

`$user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;` Creates a Personal Access Tokens that can't be refreshed.

You need to issue an OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for this. See Laravel`s Documentation about [how to issue an access token](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#issuing-access-tokens)

1. First you need to [create an app_client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#managing-clients) using the `passport:client` Artisan command
2. then you need to [raise an authorization request](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#requesting-tokens-redirecting-for-authorization)
3. [approve the request](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#approving-the-request)
4. with that you have an authorization code and can [request an access token](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#requesting-tokens-converting-authorization-codes-to-access-tokens)

The `/oauth/token` endpoint will return a JSON response containing `access_token` and a `refresh_token`.